# How to connect two Arduino via two Bluetooth Mate

Tags: android, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm new to Arduino systems and I'm trying to get help on how to connect two arduino via two Bluetooth mate for each arduino, so I can send and receive data between them.

Comment: Have you done any research of your own?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi yes i did a lot of research but they all give how to connect Bluetooth mate to android phone , and yes i tried the connection part with android but i need to connect tow arduino micro controller Via Bluetooth mate

Comment: Read the command set and datasheets. It's all in there. Basically one Arduino sends inquiry commands, finds the other arduino, pairs, then connects.